# Only update the bundle that corresponds with the changed file

Tags: gulp, webpack

I'm creating multiple bundles by using multiple entries and multiple outputs.

```
gulp.src('resources/assets/js/angular/app.js')
    .pipe(webpack({
        watch  : true,
        entry  : angularEntries(),
        output : {
            filename : "[name]Module.js"
        }
    }))
```

I'm watching a certain number of files, and when there is a change, it runs this task.

The problem is that when this task is run the first time, all the bundles are modified with stuff like this:

```
    __webpack_require__(8);
    __webpack_require__(9);
    __webpack_require__(10);
    __webpack_require__(11);
    __webpack_require__(12);
    __webpack_require__(13);
    __webpack_require__(14);
    __webpack_require__(15);

/***/ },
/* 1 */,
/* 2 */,
/* 3 */,
/* 4 */,
/* 5 */,
/* 6 */,
/* 7 */,
/* 8 */
```

How can I have webpack only update the bundle that corresponds with the changed file?